how do I implement xml validator in java spring boot?
Hi I'm now working on xml validator on spring boot but it doesnt give me the same result I got when I validate using online tools even though I alrd used the same .sch file and .xml file. can anyone help in this?
I alrd created an xml validator api
ValidationController.java

package com.example.peppol_validator.controller;

import com.example.peppol_validator.service.XmlValidationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/validate")
public class ValidationController {

    @Autowired
    private final XmlValidationService xmlValidationService;

    public ValidationController(XmlValidationService xmlValidationService) {
        this.xmlValidationService = xmlValidationService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> validateXml(@RequestParam("xmlFile") String xmlFile,
                                              @RequestParam("schemaFile") String schemaFile) {
        try {
            xmlValidationService.validateXml(xmlFile, schemaFile);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("XML is valid.");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Validation error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("IO error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

XmlValidationService
package com.example.peppol_validator.service;

import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


@Service
public class XmlValidationService {

    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public XmlValidationService(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    public void validateXml(String xmlPath, String schemaPath)  throws IOException, SAXException {
        Resource xmlResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + xmlPath);
        Resource schemaResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + schemaPath);

        try (InputStream xmlInputStream = xmlResource.getInputStream();
             InputStream schemaInputStream = schemaResource.getInputStream()) {

            DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
            parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
            parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
            parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
            parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", true);

            // Set the schema for validation
            parser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation", schemaResource.getURL().toString());

            // Use the schema input stream for validation
            parser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation", schemaPath);

            parser.parse(new InputSource(xmlInputStream)); // Change here

            System.out.println("XML is valid.");
        } catch (SAXParseException e) {
            System.out.println("XML is not valid. Error: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("XML validation error: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}


sample.xml
<ns4:Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
             xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
             xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
             xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
   <CustomizationID>urn:peppol:pint:billing-1@my-1</CustomizationID>
   <ProfileID>urn:peppol:bis:billing</ProfileID>
   <ID>PMY000676-205-20241024T065854</ID>
   <IssueDate>2024-10-24</IssueDate>
   <DueDate>2024-11-23</DueDate>
   <InvoiceTypeCode>321</InvoiceTypeCode>
   <TaxPointDate>2023-11-30</TaxPointDate>
   <DocumentCurrencyCode>MYR</DocumentCurrencyCode>
   <AccountingCost>ACC:COST:2114</AccountingCost>
   <BuyerReference>3789627992</BuyerReference>
   <ns3:InvoicePeriod>
      <StartDate>2024-10-18</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2024-11-22</EndDate>
   </ns3:InvoicePeriod>
   <ns3:OrderReference>
      <ID>PO109831</ID>
      <SalesOrderID>793</SalesOrderID>
   </ns3:OrderReference>
   <ns3:BillingReference>
      <ns3:InvoiceDocumentReference>
         <ID>53798679</ID>
         <IssueDate>2023-11-30</IssueDate>
      </ns3:InvoiceDocumentReference>
   </ns3:BillingReference>
   <ns3:DespatchDocumentReference>
      <ID>2100409</ID>
   </ns3:DespatchDocumentReference>
   <ns3:ReceiptDocumentReference>
      <ID>11</ID>
   </ns3:ReceiptDocumentReference>
   <ns3:OriginatorDocumentReference>
      <ID>0965566776</ID>
   </ns3:OriginatorDocumentReference>
   <ns3:ContractDocumentReference>
      <ID>11</ID>
   </ns3:ContractDocumentReference>
   <ns3:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <ID>Atch56890</ID>
      <DocumentDescription>Link to PDF Attchment</DocumentDescription>
      <ns3:Attachment>
         <ns3:ExternalReference>
            <URI>https://thelink</URI>
         </ns3:ExternalReference>
      </ns3:Attachment>
   </ns3:AdditionalDocumentReference>
   <ns3:ProjectReference>
      <ID>11</ID>
   </ns3:ProjectReference>
   <ns3:AccountingSupplierParty>
      <ns3:Party>
         <EndpointID schemeID="0230">051312314</EndpointID>
         <ns3:PartyIdentification>
            <ID>051312314</ID>
         </ns3:PartyIdentification>
         <ns3:PartyName>
            <Name>Monitor ERP Sdn Bhd</Name>
         </ns3:PartyName>
         <ns3:PostalAddress>
            <StreetName>18, Jalan Excellent</StreetName>
            <AdditionalStreetName>Bandar Sunway</AdditionalStreetName>
            <CityName>Petaling Jaya</CityName>
            <PostalZone>52000</PostalZone>
            <CountrySubentity>Sunway</CountrySubentity>
            <ns3:AddressLine>
               <Line>No 18</Line>
            </ns3:AddressLine>
            <ns3:Country>
               <IdentificationCode>MY</IdentificationCode>
            </ns3:Country>
         </ns3:PostalAddress>
         <ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
            <CompanyID>TIN20211100090911</CompanyID>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>GST</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
         <ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
            <CompanyID>SST20211100090911</CompanyID>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>VAT</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
         <ns3:PartyLegalEntity>
            <RegistrationName>Monitor ERP Sdn Bhd</RegistrationName>
            <CompanyID>2023010000001</CompanyID>
            <CompanyLegalForm>SENDIRIAN BERHAD</CompanyLegalForm>
         </ns3:PartyLegalEntity>
         <ns3:Contact>
            <Name>Ahmad, Danial</Name>
            <Telephone>0320334568</Telephone>
            <ElectronicMail>ahmad.danial@monitor.com.my</ElectronicMail>
         </ns3:Contact>
      </ns3:Party>
   </ns3:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <ns3:AccountingCustomerParty>
      <ns3:Party>
         <EndpointID schemeID="9922">NGTBCNTRLP1001</EndpointID>
         <ns3:PartyIdentification>
            <ID>NGTBCNTRLP1001</ID>
         </ns3:PartyIdentification>
         <ns3:PartyName>
            <Name>Amazing HQ</Name>
         </ns3:PartyName>
         <ns3:PostalAddress>
            <StreetName>Menara Amazing</StreetName>
            <AdditionalStreetName>Jalan Jalan</AdditionalStreetName>
            <CityName>Petaling Jaya</CityName>
            <PostalZone>47500</PostalZone>
            <ns3:AddressLine>
               <Line>20</Line>
            </ns3:AddressLine>
            <ns3:Country>
               <IdentificationCode>MY</IdentificationCode>
            </ns3:Country>
         </ns3:PostalAddress>
         <ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
            <CompanyID>SST20201234567</CompanyID>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>VAT</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
         <ns3:PartyLegalEntity>
            <RegistrationName>Amazing HQ</RegistrationName>
            <CompanyID>20201234567</CompanyID>
         </ns3:PartyLegalEntity>
         <ns3:Contact>
            <Name>Danny Khoo</Name>
            <Telephone>0175622845</Telephone>
            <ElectronicMail>Danny.khoo@amazing.com.my</ElectronicMail>
         </ns3:Contact>
      </ns3:Party>
   </ns3:AccountingCustomerParty>
   <ns3:PayeeParty>
      <ns3:PartyIdentification>
         <ID schemeID="0230">6715595</ID>
      </ns3:PartyIdentification>
      <ns3:PartyName>
         <Name>Amazing HQ</Name>
      </ns3:PartyName>
      <ns3:PartyLegalEntity>
         <CompanyID>6715595</CompanyID>
      </ns3:PartyLegalEntity>
   </ns3:PayeeParty>
   <ns3:TaxRepresentativeParty>
      <ns3:PartyName>
         <Name>TTMY Audit</Name>
      </ns3:PartyName>
      <ns3:PostalAddress>
         <StreetName>Unit4.02, Menara Maybank</StreetName>
         <AdditionalStreetName>Jalan Plumbum 8</AdditionalStreetName>
         <CityName>Shah Alam</CityName>
         <PostalZone>47110</PostalZone>
         <CountrySubentity>Subentity</CountrySubentity>
         <ns3:AddressLine>
            <Line>Kepayan</Line>
         </ns3:AddressLine>
         <ns3:Country>
            <IdentificationCode>MY</IdentificationCode>
         </ns3:Country>
      </ns3:PostalAddress>
      <ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
         <CompanyID>MY200824324535</CompanyID>
         <ns3:TaxScheme>
            <ID>VAT</ID>
         </ns3:TaxScheme>
      </ns3:PartyTaxScheme>
   </ns3:TaxRepresentativeParty>
   <ns3:Delivery>
      <ActualDeliveryDate>2023-11-30</ActualDeliveryDate>
      <ns3:DeliveryLocation>
         <ID schemeID="0230">7300010000001</ID>
         <ns3:Address>
            <StreetName>Jalan Amazing 88</StreetName>
            <AdditionalStreetName>Pandamaran</AdditionalStreetName>
            <CityName>Klang</CityName>
            <PostalZone>41200</PostalZone>
            <ns3:AddressLine>
               <Line>Amazing Sdn Bhd</Line>
            </ns3:AddressLine>
            <ns3:Country>
               <IdentificationCode>MY</IdentificationCode>
            </ns3:Country>
         </ns3:Address>
      </ns3:DeliveryLocation>
      <ns3:DeliveryParty>
         <ns3:PartyName>
            <Name>Monitor ERP</Name>
         </ns3:PartyName>
      </ns3:DeliveryParty>
   </ns3:Delivery>
   <ns3:PaymentMeans>
      <PaymentMeansCode name="Credit transfer">30</PaymentMeansCode>
      <PaymentID>93274234</PaymentID>
      <ns3:PayeeFinancialAccount>
         <ID>514019459999</ID>
         <Name>Ahmad Danial</Name>
         <ns3:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
            <ID>BIC32409</ID>
         </ns3:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
      </ns3:PayeeFinancialAccount>
   </ns3:PaymentMeans>
   <ns3:PaymentTerms>
      <Note>60 DAYS</Note>
   </ns3:PaymentTerms>
   <ns3:AllowanceCharge>
      <ChargeIndicator>true</ChargeIndicator>
      <AllowanceChargeReasonCode>FC</AllowanceChargeReasonCode>
      <AllowanceChargeReason>Delivery service</AllowanceChargeReason>
      <MultiplierFactorNumeric>0</MultiplierFactorNumeric>
      <Amount currencyID="MYR">0</Amount>
      <BaseAmount currencyID="MYR">0</BaseAmount>
      <ns3:TaxCategory>
         <ID>T</ID>
         <Percent>10</Percent>
         <ns3:TaxScheme>
            <ID>VAT</ID>
         </ns3:TaxScheme>
      </ns3:TaxCategory>
   </ns3:AllowanceCharge>
   <ns3:TaxTotal>
      <TaxAmount currencyID="MYR">800.00</TaxAmount>
      <ns3:TaxSubtotal>
         <TaxAmount currencyID="MYR">800.00</TaxAmount>
         <ns3:TaxCategory>
            <ID>TAX</ID>
            <Percent>10</Percent>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>GST</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:TaxCategory>
      </ns3:TaxSubtotal>
      <ns3:TaxSubtotal>
         <TaxableAmount currencyID="MYR">3000.00</TaxableAmount>
         <TaxAmount currencyID="MYR">0.00</TaxAmount>
         <ns3:TaxCategory>
            <ID>E</ID>
            <Percent>0</Percent>
            <TaxExemptionReasonCode>EEE</TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <TaxExemptionReason>Testing Exempt Tax</TaxExemptionReason>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>VAT</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:TaxCategory>
      </ns3:TaxSubtotal>
   </ns3:TaxTotal>
   <ns3:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="MYR">11000.00</LineExtensionAmount>
      <AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="MYR">0</AllowanceTotalAmount>
      <ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="MYR">0</ChargeTotalAmount>
      <PrepaidAmount currencyID="MYR">0.00</PrepaidAmount>
      <PayableRoundingAmount currencyID="MYR">0.00</PayableRoundingAmount>
      <PayableAmount currencyID="MYR">11800.00</PayableAmount>
   </ns3:LegalMonetaryTotal>
   <ns3:InvoiceLine>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Note>Please send to gate 7</Note>
      <InvoicedQuantity unitCode="EA">50</InvoicedQuantity>
      <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="MYR">3000.00</LineExtensionAmount>
      <AccountingCost>Marvel</AccountingCost>
      <ns3:OrderLineReference>
         <LineID>10</LineID>
      </ns3:OrderLineReference>
      <ns3:DocumentReference>
         <ID>Mobile number 1223432432</ID>
         <DocumentTypeCode>130</DocumentTypeCode>
      </ns3:DocumentReference>
      <ns3:Item>
         <Name>Marvel Chair AB18 Blue</Name>
         <ns3:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <ID>E</ID>
            <Percent>0</Percent>
            <TaxExemptionReasonCode>EEE</TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <TaxExemptionReason>Testing Exempt Tax</TaxExemptionReason>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>GST</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      </ns3:Item>
      <ns3:Price>
         <PriceAmount currencyID="MYR">60.00</PriceAmount>
         <BaseQuantity unitCode="EA">1</BaseQuantity>
      </ns3:Price>
   </ns3:InvoiceLine>
   <ns3:InvoiceLine>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Note>Please send to gate 5</Note>
      <InvoicedQuantity unitCode="EA">50</InvoicedQuantity>
      <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="MYR">3000.00</LineExtensionAmount>
      <AccountingCost>Marvel</AccountingCost>
      <ns3:OrderLineReference>
         <LineID>20</LineID>
      </ns3:OrderLineReference>
      <ns3:DocumentReference>
         <ID>Mobile number 1223432432</ID>
         <DocumentTypeCode>130</DocumentTypeCode>
      </ns3:DocumentReference>
      <ns3:Item>
         <Name>Marvel Chair AB18 Blue</Name>
         <ns3:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <ID>T</ID>
            <Percent>10</Percent>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>VAT</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      </ns3:Item>
      <ns3:Price>
         <PriceAmount currencyID="MYR">60.00</PriceAmount>
         <BaseQuantity unitCode="EA">1</BaseQuantity>
      </ns3:Price>
   </ns3:InvoiceLine>
   <ns3:InvoiceLine>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Note>Please send to gate 5</Note>
      <InvoicedQuantity unitCode="EA">100</InvoicedQuantity>
      <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="MYR">5000.00</LineExtensionAmount>
      <AccountingCost>Marvel</AccountingCost>
      <ns3:OrderLineReference>
         <LineID>30</LineID>
      </ns3:OrderLineReference>
      <ns3:DocumentReference>
         <ID>Mobile number 1223432432</ID>
         <DocumentTypeCode>130</DocumentTypeCode>
      </ns3:DocumentReference>
      <ns3:Item>
         <Name>Marvel Chair AB18 Blue</Name>
         <ns3:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <ID>T</ID>
            <Percent>10</Percent>
            <ns3:TaxScheme>
               <ID>VAT</ID>
            </ns3:TaxScheme>
         </ns3:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      </ns3:Item>
      <ns3:Price>
         <PriceAmount currencyID="MYR">50.00</PriceAmount>
         <BaseQuantity unitCode="EA">1</BaseQuantity>
      </ns3:Price>
   </ns3:InvoiceLine>
</ns4:Invoice>

but it keeps showing this error
[Warning] :1:1: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1#SchemaLocation?PINT-jurisdiction-aligned-rules.sch
[Error] :4:81: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ns4:Invoice'.


online tools I used https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-schematron-validator

The online tool you are using validates against a Schematron schema (which is presumably what you have got). The XML parser API you are using only supports DTD and XSD (XML Schema) validation. It's possible to invoke Schematron validation from Java, but you will need third-party software and a completely different API (which I can't advise you on).
